# Simple Cosmos DB query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a cosmos db JSON result that looks like this:

[image: Screen Shot]

How would I be able to setup a query to display for a result that contains a specific BlockNumber?

Comment: Are you asking about CosmosDB's SQL-to-JSON support, or something else? What CosmosDB client library are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is cosmos db in azure. I see the json object on the right side that comes up when i click one of the rows. I'd like to create a query for a specific block number.

Comment: If I understood your questions correctly, you are looking for `WHERE` clause in CosmosDB. So yes you can write a query which will return only specific documents. `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.BlockNumber=1234`. This query will return only those documents which matches this criteria. I hope this will help!

Comment: That worked great. Thanks. Why didn't this work for transaction hash, but this did   SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.BlockNumber=5520996

Comment: @dn18 Please edit your question to clarify, as you've now added something new to the mix (failing to query on a specific property) - and new questions shouldn't be asked in comments. Please show (in your question, not in comments) what, exactly, the issue is that you're having. Also, please swap out the graphic image of your sample document with actual formatted text representing your sample document. See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) for a list of reasons why this is important.

Answer (score 2):

AS Mahesh More's comment says,I will post it as answer to help others who have the same issue.

Use the sql:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.BlockNumber=1234
```

More details about sql,please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-getting-started).

Comment: Is there no way to query CosmosDB without SQL?